# Sonar Java - Is there a way to enforce unit test coverage?

Tags: java, unit-testing, sonarqube, code-coverage

Currently I have Sonar setup to show unit test coverage which works great. Is there a way to enforce a certain percentage of unit test coverage for a project? For example if the coverage drops below 50%, I want it to be a sonar violation and for my build to fail.

Comment: Do you use a build server of some sort (Jenkins, Teamcity)? They should be able to take the metrics from Sonar and fail the build (I know TC can).

Comment: which library are you using to get code coverage? Also which CI framework are you using?

Comment: Define a quality gate for your application.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. For example, if you use jenkins, you can configure and step in which you can choose the minimum coverage(JaCoCo Plugin).

In the jenkins job, you can pass the unit test, and take the coverage report of jacoco, and then, a step with the sonar plugin, but if the coverage is less than for instance 50%, the jenkins will show your build as failure.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install this plugin [Build Breaker](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Build+Breaker+Plugin) the only purpose of this plugin is to break the build when new alerts raise in the analysis.